# Bootstrap: tab transition issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have to change the original bootstrap CSS slightly in a tab-content in order to allow for a script to run.

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane:not(.in) {
display: none;
}
```

Is not an option here since it remove the content from the dom and blocks the script from runing.
I have tried several option, the one working best so far is :

```
.tab-content>.tab-pane:not(.in) {
display:block !important;
height:0 !important;
}
```

However the transition is "jumpy", the tab replacing the previous active one disapears for a split second, bringing everything below it up then straight back down. Not smooth at all. Do I have to resort to create the whole thing from scratch or is there a fix using bootsrap ?

edit: added more code

HTML:

`
                        JERSEYS

BIBS & SKINSUITS

```
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="jerseys" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                        <div class="nopadding">
                            <div class='slider-jerseys featured-product-box'>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-link">
                                <a class="view-product" href="">VIEW ALL JERSEYS</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="bibs" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <div class="nopadding">
                            <div class='slider-bibs featured-product-box'>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="slide slick-slide featured-product-box">
                                    <img class="carousel-picture" src="Jersey-shadow.png" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="product-link">
                                <a class="view-product" href="">VIEW ALL BIBS & SKINSUITS</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

`

CSS:

`.tab-content>.tab-pane:not(.in) {
    display:block !important;
    height:0 !important;
  }`

Comment: can you post the rest of your code so we have a [mcve] please?

Comment: You shouldn't need to override anything in such a way; why are your tabs interfering with the script that you're trying to run? Do you have to use tabs? To help diagnose this, can you please post all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, note that you can use `visibility: hidden` to hide an element without removing it from the DOM.

Comment: I am using slick slider within the tab-pane, hence the problem with loading the script inside the inactive tab-pane.
`visibility: hidden;` works on mobile however does not work on higher resolutions